# Geb : Unable to click on an element

Tags: geb

Geb automation : Failing to click on element. Can someone help me to resolve this.
Note : Button is available at left bottom of the page but it is visible.

data-haspromo="" data-element="add" id="qa_button_0" type="button" class="amain btn primary" data-formname=""  data-partnumber="12314" data-count="0" data-crossitem="" data-noncompliant="" data-partpreferred="false">Add

Here is my code to click on a button in page. It is failing to identify the element and click on it.

def clickAdd() {

```
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    waitFor (60){$("#qa_button_0").displayed}
    $('#qa_button_0').click()
    Thread.sleep(3000)

}
```

Comment: please include your exception

Comment: @DougClark : Thank you for quick reply. Issue got resolved after below statement is the code :   waitFor (60){$("#qa_button_0").displayed}

Comment: if you are waiting, you can probably remove your Thread.sleep calls

Comment: @DougClark : Yes, I removed it later. Thank you.